# Does dropping a database user drop triggers the user has raised on tables from other schemas?

Tags: database, oracle

Assuming a user USER1 has created triggers on various tables, all of which are not owned by this user but these triggers record data to USER1 tables.

Now, if I drop a user in Oracle using the following command, will this drop all these other triggers as well?

SQL>drop user USER cascade;

If not, the triggers will not work as they will not find the destination tables to write to. Also, is there a way to drop all triggers raised by a database user irrespective of the schema to which they belong?

Comment: If the user is dropped but the triggers are not who would own them?

Answer (score 1):

A simple test shows that the triggers will be dropped. I created a new user `TEST2`, granted it `CREATE ANY TRIGGER`, then created a single trigger on `PHIL.BIGTABLE`.

```
PHIL@PHILL11G2 > select count(*) from dba_triggers;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       617

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > drop user test2 cascade;

User dropped.

PHIL@PHILL11G2 > select count(*) from dba_triggers;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       616

PHIL@PHILL11G2 >
```

Answer (score 0):

Trigger metadata is in DBA_TRIGGERS, so dropping them is a matter of:

```
begin
  for x in (
    select owner,
           trigger_name
    from   dba_triggers
    where  ... -- apply predicate to select triggers here)
  loop
    execute immediate 'drop trigger '||x.owner||'.'||x.trigger_name;
  end loop;
end;
/
```